# Question on installing ski rack on on 36" wall space

Tags: wood, walls, garage, screws, mounting

I am trying to install ski rack on 36" wall space backed by 2 studs. To utilize maximum space, I think putting 2x4 wood board on wall fastened to 2 studs, and install ski rack on top of the board. Then, I don't need to align location of stud with screw hole of ski rack which gives whole space utilization. Before doing this, I want to double-check my ideas as follows.

- Is my idea reasonable?
- Aiming 150 lbs load capacity, what type of screw / how many of them needs to be used to fasten the board and studs?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming not much is as stake, the idea is reasonable if the rack will still 'work' when it is 1.5" from the wall.  I suggest screws or lags of whatever type you have on hand, long enough to drive 1.5" into the stud, placed 3/4" from the top of the 2x4 cleat, one per stud, assuming you can tighten the screws enough to fasten the cleat tightly to the wall. Then mount the ski rack to the middle or lower half of the cleat.  Be careful of electrical and plumbing in the wall. However, all that's a lot of extra work that will end up looking cludgy.  I'd be more inclined to drill new holes in the rack that align with the studs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with User217623 on drilling the Ski-Rack to hit the studs with Lag screws. However, the 2x4 idea is fine, I'd go with Tee-Nuts on the backside of the 2x4's for the Ski-Rack mounting, so you can use large bolts.

Use thick or double washers on everything, except the Tee-Nuts of course. Even Douglas Fir 2x4's are quite soft & will loosen over time at the 2x4 mounting points. Also, use the 2x4's for more. Screw-in hooks to hang gloves, boots & poles (to the bottoms of the 2x4's & not just the ends)...if needed. Even sandwich a tarp between the top 2x4 & wall for visual security & dust avoidance.